# Magento currency symbol position - Euro for English language

Tags: currency, locale

I am using Magento v1.9.1.0. and I have a problem with currency symbol position when having locale set to English and currency to Euro. It displays:

€24.10

I would like to show it like where locale is set to Slovenian and currency to Euro:

24.10 €

If I change 'lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml' currency format, then it won't display like it should for US dollars currency symbol($).

Does anyone know the solution for that kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is ok for store in English language to display currency symbol before value, because the position of currency symbol € is different in every country and it depends on grammar. So, €24.10 will be fine. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Congratulations!  Please accept a correct answer anyway as you may not be the only person to ask this question in the History of the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

You can observe `currency_display_options_forming` event dispatched in `Mage_Core_Model_Locale class`

```
<currency_display_options_forming>
    <observers>
        <foo_bar>
            <class>foo_bar/observer</class>
            <method>currencyDisplayOptionsForming</method>
        </foo_bar>
    </observers>
</currency_display_options_forming>
```

Observer:

```
class Foo_Bar_Model_Observer
{
    public function currencyDisplayOptionsForming(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode() == 'en_US' &&
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode() == 'EUR'
        ) {
            $options = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
            $options['position'] = Zend_Currency::RIGHT;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Look in `Zend_Currency` class for additional options.

Comment: that did positioned the curr on right side, but without padding, or space between number and sign! I feel that in that case best bet is fiddle with xml files in `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data` dir,, which is totaly putting it off :(

Answer (score 0):

You can customize it at price.phtml .

```
$locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();

 $currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency()->getSymbol();

 if($locale=='sl_SI') { 

echo $_price;echo $currencySymbol; 

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I want. I have $locale set to en_US and $currencySymbol with your code gives me $, but my currency set in admin is €. My question was if it is possible to have locale set to 'en_US' and currency to '€' so that it displays like that: 24.10€ and not €24.10. But thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

go to ( lib/Zend/Currency.php ) move to line 196

```
if ($options['position'] !== self::STANDARD) {
    $value = str_replace('¤', '', $value);
    $space = '';
    if (iconv_strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
        $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        $space = ' ';
    }

    if ($options['position'] == self::LEFT) {
        $value = '¤' . $space . $value;//here the currency before the value (price)
    } else {
        $value = $value . $space . '¤';
    }
}
```

TO MAKE THE CURRENCY AFTER THE VALUE (PRICE) :

```
if ($options['position'] !== self::STANDARD) {
    $value = str_replace('¤', '', $value);
    $space = ' ';//make space between the value and the currency
    if (iconv_strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
        $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        $space = ' ';
    }

    if ($options['position'] == self::LEFT) {
        $value = $value . $space . '¤' ;//print the currency after the value
    } else {
        $value = $value . $space . '¤';
    }
}
```